angular custom package missing specifier
I have created an angular custom package (angular 17.3) in which there is a service.
After publish, I install the package and am able to see the service. But I have en error
An unhandled exception occurred: Missing "./lib/services/my-service.service" specifier in "@company/my-lib" package
Here is my installed package architecture :

Here is the content of the public_api.ts :
export * from './lib/component/scanner/scanner.component';
export * from './lib/services/my-service.service';
export * from './lib/services/utils.service';
export * from './lib/model/my-model';
export * from './lib/my-lib-constants';

[edit]
The service is imported as following in the project that throws the error :
import {
  MyServiceService
} from "@company/my-lib/lib/services/my-service.service";

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?
Thank you for your help

Can you add the code where the service is imported?

hi JSON, import code has been added

ng-packagr will create one single entrypoint @company/my-lib which exposes all symbols that have been exported in public_api.ts. Which means, your import needs to look like the following:
import { MyServiceService } from "@company/my-lib";


holy molly, thank you so much -_-
